# Facebook.com returning invalid security certificate

Tags: firefox, security, certificate

I am on a network which is secured by Cyberroam in my University. Recently, they have made some changes to their security policy and have 'blocked' facebook.com.

I kind of used to think that blocking `https` sites is quite not possible since the connection is encrypted.

Q1. How did they achieve this?
Q2. Is it possible to access facebook.com on this connection in any way?

I am getting the error: `This connection is untrusted. This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.`

Thanks

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess.  The University is handling the secure connection to Facebook.com themselves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox: This connection is untrusted + Behind corporate firewall](http://superuser.com/questions/115349/firefox-this-connection-is-untrusted-behind-corporate-firewall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS in HTTPS protects the HTTP request, but it doesn't protect the lower layers. That is, a HTTPS website can still be blocked by inspecting the TLS "Server Name Indication" header (the same feature that's used for HTTPS virtual hosting), or by IP address (if the client doesn't request any specific server via TLS SNI), both of which are sent outside the TLS tunnel.

---

However, Cyberroam in your case does neither; it uses the sledgehammer approach – it intercepts all HTTPS handshakes, decrypts the connection by pretending that it's the client, inspects it, and re-encrypts it using its own TLS certificate. So instead of a single TLS handshake...

- web server ⇆ browser

...you now have two:

- web server ⇆ firewall (pretending to be the browser)
- firewall (pretending to be the server) ⇆ browser

Basically, your firewall is performing a [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) against you.

---

Since the firewall obviously doesn't have Facebook's real TLS certificate, it generates its own.

Now, *usually*, since the web server has an unrecognized certificate, the browser would ask you whether you want to disregard that or whether you'd rather run to safety. (In corporate environments, the firewall's certificate might even be preinstalled to all workstations.)

However, when you visited Facebook last time, its server informed the browser using [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) that it should be locked to 'secure' mode. That is, as long as HSTS is active for Facebook's site, the browser will always use HTTPS even if you tried to visit that site over `http://`, and it won't let you override bad-certificate errors like the one you got, because there isn't any way to distinguish Cyberroam from a real malicious attack.

In addition, Firefox and Chrome even hardcode the certificate information for some websites (Google and Facebook included), so even if your OS trusted the fake certificate, you still couldn't visit Google, because the browser knows that "only authorities X and Y, and nobody else, may issue certificates for google.com". (I think this is called certificate pinning, or preloading, or something such?)

Comment: This explanation is awesome. Thanks a lot. Now can you tell a way how to bypass it and access facebook.com on this network?

Comment: @SuperLoser: Yes, ask the University network admins to unblock the site.

Comment: Haha, thank you so much anyway. The post helped.

Comment: @Super Loser : There might be other ways to bypass this; like using a VPN, which basically re-routes the traffic.  Of course, the university might block common approaches of implementing a VPN.  You could end up with a cat-and-mouse game, which you might ultimately lose as you might also risk violating some sort of University policy, which might give you some really bad consequences (like forced withdrawal, banishment from enrolling in University classes).  Best bet might be to bypass the University net by using wireless comm to a nearby tower run by phone company.  Works,safer, more expensive