# Firefox Sync and Zscaler Firewall/Proxy not working

Tags: firefox, proxy, sync, firewall

Our network has been recently upgraded with the zscaler proxy solution. I was able to regain internet access by following this question: [Firefox: This connection is untrusted + Behind corporate firewall](https://superuser.com/questions/115349/)

Unfortunately, that did not work out for Firefox Sync.

I'm able to log-in (verified by getting a mail from Firefox Accounts) but Firefox isn't still able to sync.

I suspect that is somehow related to the certification signing process what is properly blocked by zscaler:

`1443703953083  FirefoxAccounts ERROR   error POSTing /certificate/sign: {"code":401,"errno":109,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Missing authentication","info":"https://github.com/mozilla/fxa-auth-server/blob/master/docs/api.md#response-format"}`

Answer (score 1):

Bypass the proxy for `*.services.mozilla.com`; I believe Firefox browser pins the cert for Sync.

If using PAC, use a line like:

```
shExpMatch(host, "*.services.mozilla.com")
```

If using PBR, WCCP or a Tunnel, bypass it at that edge device.

Comment: can provide some more details, I reckon you mean:
PAC = proxy auto-config file
PBR =  Policy Based Routing 
WCCP = Web Cache Communication Protocol
It seams I can download the PAC file although I cannot read the entire url in LAN Settings of Win 7 and haven't found a command for cmd to do so yet.
Do you want me to edit the PAC save it locally and point firefox to it?
Beware I'm not system or it admin.

Comment: can you provide some details?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the perfect answer but there is a [ticket on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1219219) what has gone in some more details recently what I cannot cover here in a compressive and satisfying answer.
I hope the reference to Bugzilla may help others to find a solution.
All that I can say that as from Firefox V54 sync works may even as from V53 but I cannot tell the reason.